# Using EventLoopGroup in Netty with Multiple Channels

Tags: java, netty, event-loop

I am new to Netty but unfortunately there seems to be no detailed documentation/tutorial for a beginner.

I have multiple threads, each creating separate clients to connect to separate channels, using `NettyChannelBuilder`. The idea is that each channel will send & receive different kind of messages to/from different hosts. E.g. it looks like this:

```
class MyServiceClass{
  void executeTasks() {
      ...
      //here multiple tasks are executed in a for loop
      executorService.execute(new Task(new Client());
      ...
  }
}

class Client {
  ..
  void connect() {
      channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).build();
  }
}
```

In this case, each task has its own client and clients are building their own channels to receive messages.

Should i create a single `EventLoopGroup` at executeTasks and give it to the Clients to be used while building their channel.
If this is the case, what is the advantage of using `EventLoopGroup`? What is it exactly doing at the background?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. EventLoopGroups are just a grouping of threads used for netty. Using netty your clients will be on an EventLoopGroup and will be assigned to threads in a round robin matter so some may be on the same thread.

Personally I find the docs to be great but it's definitely not a framework designed for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with an example. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: NettyChannelBuilder is in the grpc package not netty, I don't know much about grpc looks like they handle the event loop creation for you.I wouldnt worry about passing an event loop in until you need extra control for it.